# Start and stop a service using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to stop a service and then restart the service once it has finished stopping.
I am using c# and have produced the following code. The problem is: if the service is started it will stop the service but not restart the service. If the service is stopped the next time the function is called it will just start the service.

```
string strCmdText1, strCmdText2;
strCmdText1 = "NET STOP \"AdmnService\"";
strCmdText2 = "NET START \"AdmnService\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C" + strCmdText1);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C" + strCmdText2);
```

Is there a way to concatenate the commands into one line? I am not sure what the /C does but perhaps there is some other switch to execute two commands.

Comment: Could you just create a batch file to do the 2 commands, then use c# to start the batch file?

Comment: exactly what i was thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) (in the System.ServiceProcess .Net 4 assembly). Here's a simple Console application showing how:

```
        ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("AdmnService");
        controller.Stop();

        controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
        Console.WriteLine("Service status: " + controller.Status);

        controller.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Service status: " + controller.Status);
```

Comment: this worked great! thnks

Answer (score 3):

[ServiceController.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will do start for you... The other methods of this class let you check status and stop service.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.

Using the Status property you can find out the status of the service and start it again or use the [WaitForStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.waitforstatus%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to be signalled