# Auto-Stop a Console Service after the work is finished

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-5

I have a console app that is built using `IService`s, like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    // ...
    var serviceToUse = args[0];

    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            switch (serviceToUse) {
                case "first": { services.AddTransient<IService, AlphaService>(); break; }
                case "second": { services.AddTransient<IService, BetaService>(); break; }
            }
        })
        .UseSerilog()
        .Build();

    IService svc;

    if (serviceToUse == "alpha") {
        svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<AlphaService>(host.Services);
    }
    else {
        svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<BetaService>(host.Services);
    }

    List<Entity> entities = Common.GetEntities();
    
    svc.Run(modeToUse, entities);
}
```

my service is like this:

```
public class AlphaService : IHostedService {
    public AlphaService(ILogger<AlphaService> log, IConfiguration config) {
        _log = log;
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        // update entities
        AlphaRepository.ProcessEntities(_config, alphaEntities);
    }
}
```

with

```
public interface IService {
    public void Run(string arg, IEnumerable<Entity> alphaEntities);
}
```

The problem is that the application never ends, even if the services ended its works. Is there a way to "kill" the application after the work is finished?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the service when it is done, and you need to use a service controller to check for the service status and close the app when the service stat is closed.

[ServiceController Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

This answer may help

[Start and stop a service using c# [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097705/start-and-stop-a-service-using-c-sharp)

Note that in an application that have several threads or running services you must call

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

to end the application to end the application or it will stuck in the background waiting for events from the services or threads.

Comment: I effectively didn't mentioned that the service is inherited actually from *`IHostedService`*, so is acting like a BackgroundWorker. So, as I understood, at the end of the second (and last) service StartAsync() method I should not just "return", but rather `Environment.Exit(0)`

Comment: Yes, as when you run services and threads that remain active you will need to explicitly call Environment.Exit(0) to force the application to quit, or you will need to make sure they are inactive before you reach the end of main().

Comment: thank you, please see the related question, this one is maybe not clearly described https://stackoverflow.com/q/66116983/961631